# recursive template types

Tags: c++

I want to make following code snippet to work

```
typedef boost::function<result_type ()> functor_type;
typedef boost::variant<int, functor_type> result_type;
```

two types depend on each other, how to break the circular dependencies?

---

The Motivation

Basicly, I want to implement tail call in c++, like this

```
template<typename ResultT>
struct TailCall
{
    typedef ResultT result_type;
    typedef boost::function<ret_type ()> continuation_type;
    typedef boost::variant<result_type, continuation_type> ret_type;

    TailCall(const continuation_type& init) : next(init) {}

    result_type operator()()
    {
         while (true) {
            ret_type r = next();
            result_type *result = boost::get<result_type>(&r);
            if (result)
                return *result;
            else
                next = boost::get<continuation_type>(r);
         }
    }

private:
    continuation_type next;
};

TailCall<int>::ret_type fibonacci_impl(int term, int val, int prev)
{
    if (term == 0) return prev;
    if (term == 1) return val;
    return boost::bind(fibonacci_impl, term-1, val+prev, val);
}

int fibonacci(int index)
{
    TailCall<int> fib(boost::bind(fibonacci_impl, index, 1, 0));
    return fib();
}
```

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to do this :(

Comment: It might help if you explain (by editing the question) what you are trying to do, and how you are going to use these typedef types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost variant has two specific utilities (recursive_variant and recursive_wrapper) to do that.

Here an example using recursive_wrapper

```
struct functor_type;

typedef boost::variant<int,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<functor_type> > result_type;

struct functor_type : public boost::function<result_type()> {
      using boost::function<result_type()>::boost::function<result_type()>;
};
```

Comment: Actually I'd appreciate if someone can post a solution which uses recursive_variant. I can't manage to get that work for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at `boost::recursive_variant`.

An example from the [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) examples:

```
    struct mini_xml;

    typedef
        boost::variant<
            boost::recursive_wrapper<mini_xml>
          , std::string
        >
    mini_xml_node;

    struct mini_xml
    {
        std::string name;                           // tag name
        std::vector<mini_xml_node> children;        // children
    };
}
```